Randomization Based on Criteria in SAS
I would like to randomly re-assign records based on criteria. For example in the table below, I would like to re-assign 30% of records where the ID is 4 to be an ID of 2, and 10% of the records where the ID is 3 to be an ID of 2. I have looked into the rand function using both bernoulli and uniform and can't seem to get it right.
I believe using the rand("uniform") or rand("bernoulli") functions is what would work best, but I can't seem to get the code dynamic enough to account for the specific percentages and also re-assign based on two different criteria.
Example Table

Welcome :-) Where do the values 30% of records where ID = 4 come from? Are those in a separate table?

@PeterClemmensen The whole point of Staging Ground is to clarify such things there, before it gets published.
